# Consume ArcGIS Map Service into MapBox GL API?

Tags: mapbox, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Can someone provide a code sample to consume an ArcGIS Map Service into MapBox GL API?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Map services serve up images, gl is vector.

Comment: Is it someone else map service, or yours?  If the latter, you can publish your map service as a vector tile layer using ArcGIS Pro. See https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/vector-tile-layers.htm

Answer (score 9):

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #map1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 49%;
    }

    #map2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 51%;
        width: 49%;
    }

    #map1_label,
    #map2_label {
        padding: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 10;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
    }

    #map1_label {
        left: 10;
    }

    #map2_label {
        left: 51%;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div id="map1_label">Dynamic Map Service</div>
<div id="map2_label">Cached Map Service</div>
<div id='map1'></div>
<div id='map2'></div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'your-mapbox-api-key';
    var map1 = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map1',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
        center: [153.021072, -27.470125],
        zoom: 15
    });

    var map2 = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map2',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
        center: [153.021072, -27.470125],
        zoom: 15
    });

    map1.on('load', function() {
        map1.addLayer({
            "id": "dynamic-demo",
            "type": "raster",
            "minzoom": 0,
            "maxzoom": 22,
            "source": {
                "type": "raster",
                "tiles": ['https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/export?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png32&layers=show%3A0&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&bboxSR=EPSG:3857&imageSR=EPSG:3857&size=256,256&f=image'],
                "tileSize": 256
            }
        });
    });

    map2.on('load', function() {
        map2.addLayer({
            "id": "cache-demo",
            "type": "raster",
            "minzoom": 0,
            "maxzoom": 22,
            "source": {
                "type": "raster",
                "tiles": ['https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'],
                "tileSize": 256
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, however, just in case this helps anyone, see above: (two maps: one with dynamic service, the other with a cached service)

Comment: Thanks! The dynamic solution worked very well for me on Android, except I needed to put "imageSR=3857&bboxSR=3857"

Answer (score -1):

Mapbox GL only consumes vector tiles compatible with Mapbox Vector Tiles spec [1].

If ArcGIS Map Service provides compatible vector tiles, you could probably create a style with a tile source pointing to the service you mentioned [2].

[1] https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/

[2] https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've seen people post that they have accomplished this.  I just need a code sample to get me going.  Here is a public ArcGIS end-point.  Maybe possible via WMS?  I'm interested in overlaying various weather related services. http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nowcoast/radar_meteo_imagery_nexrad_time/MapServer

Comment: ArcGIS as WMS: http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/nowcoast/radar_meteo_imagery_nexrad_time/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Comment: MapboxGL can consume raster tile sources and wms sources. See their style spec for more info: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/ as well as: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/